# groovy group by name and pick the latest by date in file name

Tags: groovy

below is the list of files :

```
abc_2019_01_30_5816789.bak, abc_2019_01_31_2992794.bak, 
xyz_2019_01_26_4690992.bak, xyz_2019_01_27_8319704.bak, 
pqr_2019_01_30_5986789.bak, pqr_2019_01_31_3142809.bak, 
test_2019_01_30_6076789.bak, test_2019_01_31_3232818.bak, 
testing_2019_01_30_6026789.bak, testing_2019_01_31_3192814.bak, 
repair_2019_01_30_6116789.bak, repair_2019_01_31_3282823.bak, 
factory_2019_01_30_5646789.bak, factory_2019_01_31_2802775.bak
```

i have this list in "parsedlist", so when i sort them and pick the latest 7, i see a couple of duplicate files. my requirement is to have 7 unique files which are latest and write them to a text file. I have tried the below code :

```
List<String> sortedList = parsedList.sort(false).reverse()
println sortedList.take(7)
String filename = "D:\\latest.txt"
new File(filename).write(sortedList.take(7).join(","))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just sorting the list by the full filename, which gives you all the "xyz" files first, then "testing" and so on...

One way would be to use `groupBy` to first group the files by prefix, then sort each group and finally pick the last item from each group.

```
println parsedList
    .groupBy{it[0..-24]} // group by prefix (remove timestamp), results in a map like [abc:['abc_2019_...', 'abc_2019_...'], xyz:[...], ...]
    .values() // collect the values from the KeyValuePairs (i.e. just the lists with the strings) --> [['abc_2019_...', 'abc_...'], ['xyz_...','xyz_...'], ...]
    *.sort() // sort each of the lists
    *.getAt(-1) // from each list take the last item
```

[Groovy web console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5098432498761728)

Comment: Just curious if the file names are like "abc_production_backup__2019_01_30_5816789.bak" , then group by would be ?

Comment: Should work just the same. The regex replace only removes the trailing timestamp.

Comment: Since your timestamp is always the same length we don't even need the regex, just remove the last 23 characters. I have updated the answer (and web console link) to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for fun (as there are many ways to do things in Groovy)

```
println parsedList.groupBy { it.split(/_\d{4}_/).head() }
    .collect { k, v -> v.sort().last() }
```